# setting up cygwin via the GUI

Tags: cygwin, installation

I have a standalone server running Cygwin -- I did not setup this server, it was inherited.  Anyway, I'd like to know what options the installing admin selected in the setup program.

I've read that I could look in /etc/setup, /etc/postinstall, or /etc/preremove but there are a lot of packages in those directories... same goes for the output of cygcheck -c.

I don't want to know every single library on the system... just how to duplicate the install.  Is there a way to determine which packages were select in the GUI setup program?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Read carefully the http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: When I run setup.exe, there is a tree of packages one can install if they choose to select it.  I do know that on the server in question, they didn't install everything (at that's several Gig if one chooses to install everything).  How do I determine what packages were marked for install in the tree???  running cygcheck prints out dozens and dozens of lines of libraries.  I'd prefer to NOT trace all those libraries to packages to determine what was selected in the setup.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin is pretty standalone. You should be able to archive up the entire Cygwin directory (and subdirectories) and move it to the same location on another system.

If you archive it up I recommend 7-zip. You can get it free [here](http://www.7-zip.org/). The built in Windows archiver can create permission problems when an archive is extracted on a destination system. I recommend 7-zip for both archiving and unarchiving. If you use the built in Windows archiver and then move it to the new system and extract it - it will extract without errors. However you may find things don't actually work right while using some Cygwin applications

If you don't copy everything you won't move any of the original admin's custom changes.